# Storyboard PeformSegue

Tags: ios5, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

There has to be a very simple solution to this, but it has been racking my brain!

I have an app that presents a "Login" screen on app launch if a Facebook session is not valid and it proceeds to show the main screen if a Facebook session is valid. All of this defined in my AppDelegate.m

That works just fine when the app launches. It choses the right viewController if Facebook is or isn't logged in.

My issue is with the Login screen that is presented if Facebook is not logged in. It is a UIViewController and has a UIButton that logs in the user, when the user is logged in it SHOULD perform a segue to the main view which is a UITableViewController with an embedded NavigationController.

I have tried using:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fbLoginYes" sender:self];
```

But it never segues, even when triggered directly from the button.

Is there some issue with triggering a segue like this? i.e. ViewController to TableViewController?

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's an image of my Storyboard:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of a segue is it? Is it a Push?
And do you really have a UINavigationController embedded in a UITableViewController? Or is it the other way around?

The first thing I would check though is the name of the Segue in your Storyboard. Also, in a view controller that is launching a segue, you can catch a method named `-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`. Try putting a breakpoint into it and see whether it gets called. If it does, the problem is probably in the actual segue and if it doesn't, it just means you are not invoking the segue right.

Comment: I added a screenshot so you can see what I'm working with. It is a Push Segue that is connected, not to a button, but from the view controller to the Navigation controller...I have it being called like this:

Comment: NSNotificationCenter calls the showLoggedIn method when the app Enters the foreground, the showLoggedIn method uses    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fbLoginYes" sender:self]; to perform the segue...the segue is not triggered, even though the showLoggedIn method is.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to embed your login (root) viewController in a Nav Controller?

Comment: I tried embedding the login in a Nav Controller and still it wasn't called. I did find that using this code worked, but it messes up the navigation of my app: UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
    ECSlidingViewController *slideVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTop"];
    [self presentViewController:slideVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: I found out it was an issue with Xcode itself. Something to do with the compiler. I had to remove it all and re-install a new copy. Works just fine now!

Comment: Great, sorry I wasn't of more help.